# How can I compare one field with another in NRQL?

Tags: newrelic, nrql

How can I make this kind of query in NRQL?

```
SELECT origin, destination FROM locations WHERE origin = destination
```

Comment: It worked exactly this way for me. What issue did you have?

Comment: It returned results where origin and destination were different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option for this to use a subquery like this

```
SELECT origin, destination FROM locations WHERE origin IN (SELECT destination FROM locations)
```

Comment: I think that's what I did in the end.